# Invalid property 'maximumActive' of bean class

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am getting this error when trying to connect to ActiveMQ.

```
ConnectException: Invalid property 'maximumActive' of bean class [org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory]: Bean property 'maximumActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I'm not sure what does it mean. Did I miss something in the bean creation?

I have this setting :

```xml
<bean id="llmJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="20" />
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="llmJmsConnectionFactoryBase" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the property is different:

```
maximumActiveSessionPerConnection
```

Try that instead in your Spring config.

Comment: I do have this setting

Comment: Then you'll need to show your config code, unless we can only guess where the "maximumActive" property comes from.